# How do I change the values of a nested list without flattening it?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists. A regular list, and nested list with numbers that are indexes of the other list, like so:

```py
>>> mylist = ['hi', 'hello', 'bye', 'cya']
>>> myindexes = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]]]
```

How do I change all of the indices in `myindexes` to items from `mylist` with those indices without flattening `myindexes`?

Like this:

```py
>>> replace_indexes_with_list_items(myindexes)
[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']], [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']], [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```

Note that it is a regularly nested list.

I've tried this:

```py
>>> myindexes = [mylist[a] for c in myindexes for b in c for a in b]
```

but it flattens the list:

```py
['hi', 'hello', 'bye', 'cya', 'hi', 'bye', 'hello', 'cya', 'hi', 'cya', 'hello', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach would be:

```
>>> [[[mylist[i], mylist[j]], [mylist[k], mylist[l]]] for [i, j], [k, l] in myindexes]

[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```

Or this,

```
>>> [[[mylist[i3] for i3 in i2] for i2 in i1] for i1 in myindexes]
[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```

If you are willing to try `numpy`, [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.vectorize(mylist.__getitem__)(myindexes).tolist()
[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```

Or, [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

```
>>> np.take(mylist, myindexes).tolist()
[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']],
 [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of the loops and nest the list comprehensions to match the nesting of `myindexes`:

```
>>> [[[mylist[a] for a in b] for b in c] for c in myindexes]
[[['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'cya']], [['hi', 'bye'], ['hello', 'cya']], [['hi', 'cya'], ['hello', 'bye']]]
```